# Matrix multiplication error with Open MPI

Tags: c, memory-management, parallel-processing, openmpi, dynamic-allocation

Im trying to compute a NxN matrix multiplication using the OpenMPI and C. Everything runs as expected, except for the `MPI_Bcast()`. As far as I understand, the MASTER must broadcast `matrix_2` to the rest of the WORKER processes. At the same time, when WORKERS reach the `MPI_Bcast()` they should wait there until the selected process (in this case the MASTER) does the broadcast.

The error I'm getting is a *Segmentation fault* and *Address not mapped*, so it surely has something to do with the dynamic allocation of the matrices. What I do is send parts of `matrix_1` to each process, and each one of them then does partial multiplications and additions with the previously broadcast `matrix_2`.

I know that the error must be on the `MPI_Bcast()` because when I comment it the program finishes correctly (but obviously without computing the product). There must be something I'm not being aware of. I leave both the code and the error message I got. Thanks in advanced.

**CODE**

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
/* MACROS */
#define MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG 1
#define SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG 4 
#define MASTER 0 
#define WORKER 1

int *matrix_1;
int *matrix_2;

int *result;

double start_time;
double end_time;

int procID;
int numProc; 

int size, numRows, from, to;
int i,j,k;

MPI_Status status;
MPI_Request request;

void addressMatrixMemory(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    size = atoi(argv[1]);
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procID); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProc); 

    addressMatrixMemory(size);

    /* MASTER starts. */
    if(procID == MASTER){

        start_time = MPI_Wtime();
        for(i = 1; i < numProc; i++){
            numRows = size/(numProc - 1); 

            from = (i - 1) * numRows; 

            if(((i + 1) == numProc) && ((size % (numProc - 1))) != 0){
                to = size; 
            } else {
                to = from + numRows; 
            }
            MPI_Isend(&from, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

            MPI_Isend(&to, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

            MPI_Isend(matrix_1, (to - from) * size, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

        }

    }

    MPI_Bcast(&matrix_2, size * size, MPI_INT, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /* WORKERS task */

    if(procID >= WORKER){
        int row, col;
        int *matrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix_1[0])*size*size);

        MPI_Recv(&from, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        MPI_Recv(&to, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 

        MPI_Recv(matrix, (to - from) * size, MPI_INT, MASTER, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        for(row = from; row < to; row++){
            for(col = 0; col < size; col++){
                result[row * size + col] = 0;
                for(k = 0; k < size; k++);
                    result[row * size + col] += matrix[row * size + k] * matrix_2[k * size + col];
            }
        }
        MPI_Isend(&from, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Isend(&to, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Isend(&result[from], (to - from) * size, MPI_INT, MASTER, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    }

    /* MASTER gathers WORKERS job. */
    if(procID == MASTER){
        for(i = 1; i < numProc; i++){
            MPI_Recv(&from, 1, MPI_INT, i, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&to, 1, MPI_INT, i, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&result[from], (to - from) * size, MPI_INT, i, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }

        end_time = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("\nRunning Time = %f\n\n", end_time - start_time);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    free(matrix_1);
    free(matrix_2);
    free(result);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void addressMatrixMemory(int n){
    matrix_1 = malloc(sizeof(matrix_1[0])*n*n);
    matrix_2 = malloc(sizeof(matrix_2[0])*n*n);

    result = malloc(sizeof(result[0])*n*n);

    /* Matrix init with values between 1 y 100. */
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % 100 + 1;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n*n; i++){
        matrix_1[i] = r;
        r = rand() % 100 + 1;
        matrix_2[i] = r;
        r = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
[tuliansPC:28270] *** Process received signal ***
[tuliansPC:28270] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[tuliansPC:28270] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[tuliansPC:28270] Failing at address: 0x603680
    [tuliansPC:28270] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7f0a98ce0340]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x97ffe) [0x7f0a9899fffe]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 2] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_convertor_pack+0x129) [0x7f0a98fef779]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 3] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_sm.so(mca_btl_sm_prepare_src+0x1fd) [0x7f0a923c385d]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 4] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_send_request_start_rndv+0x1dc) [0x7f0a93245c9c]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 5] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_isend+0x8ec) [0x7f0a9323856c]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 6] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_generic+0x3fc) [0x7f0a914f49fc]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 7] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_pipeline+0xbc) [0x7f0a914f4d5c]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 8] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed+0x134) [0x7f0a914ec7a4]
[tuliansPC:28270] [ 9] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sync.so(mca_coll_sync_bcast+0x64) [0x7f0a917096a4]
[tuliansPC:28270] [10] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(MPI_Bcast+0x13d) [0x7f0a98f5678d]
[tuliansPC:28270] [11] ej5Exec() [0x400e8c]
[tuliansPC:28270] [12] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f0a98929ec5]
[tuliansPC:28270] [13] ej5Exec() [0x400ac9]
[tuliansPC:28270] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 28270 on node tuliansPC exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first problem that jumps out. You're using non-blocking communication incorrectly. `MPI_Isend` is a non-blocking send function which means that when you call `MPI_Isend`, all you are really doing is telling MPI about a message that you'd like to send at some point in the future. It may get sent right then, it may not. In order to guarantee that the data is actually sent, you need to complete the call with something like `MPI_Wait`.Usually when people use non-blocking calls (`MPI_Isend`), they don't mix them with blocking calls (`MPI_Recv`). If you use all non-blocking calls, then you can have all of them complete with a single function, `MPI_Waitall`.

Try fixing these issues first and see if that solves your problem. Just because you commented out the collective, doesn't mean that the other issues weren't there. MPI programs can be notoriously difficult to debug because of weird behavior like this.

Comment: I tried adding the `MPI_Wait()` after each `MPI_Isend()` but I get the same errors.